# Singly linked list doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I was playing around with Linked list to get used to it a little bit, but I can't make this little program work. I don't know what is wrong here, help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//Struct
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node NODE;

//Function Declaration
NODE* addNode (NODE* pList, NODE* pPre, int data);
void printList (NODE* pList);

int main (void)
{
    //Local Declaration
    NODE *pPre;
    NODE *pList;

    //Statement
    pList = addNode (pList, pPre, 10);
    pList = addNode (pList, pPre, 20);
    pList = addNode (pList, pPre, 30);

    printList (pList);
    return 0;
}

NODE* addNode (NODE* pList, NODE* pPre, int data)
{
    //Local Declaration
    NODE* pNew;

    //Statement
    if (!(pNew = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE))))
    {
        printf("\aMemory overflow in insert\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pNew->value = data;
    if (pPre == NULL)
    {
        //Inserting before first node or to empty list.
        pNew->next = pList;
        pList = pNew;
    }
    else
    {
        pNew->next = pPre->next;
        pPre->next = pNew;
    }
    return pList;
}
void printList (NODE* pList)
{
    //Local Declaration
    NODE* pNew;

    //Statement

    pNew = pList;
    while(pNew)
    {
        printf("%d", pNew->value);
        pNew = pNew->next;

    }
    return;
}
```

pPre is the predecessor node, and pList is the pointer to the list.

Comment: ``return;``? Return what?

Comment: @gongzhitaao, I'm not sure I follow.  That's in a function returning `void` - what's the problem?

Comment: @CarlNorum, check the edit history ;-)  (click on the timestamp after the "edited" indicator)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't assigned NULL to pointers **pPre** and **PList**, Try the following code, it runs O.K. Now,

```
NODE *pPre=NULL;
NODE *pList=NULL;
```

Comment: This code is based on the text book that I'm reading. Don't we have to define what `pPre` is? so that the compiler know what it is

Comment: NODE *pPre is actually struct Node * pPre because of the typedef statement.

Comment: That would make `NODE *pPre`. I think that's the whole point of using `typedef`

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd Your text book is making a (very dangerous) assumption that local variables will be auto-initialized to NULL.  That is not always guaranteed.  To initialize your lists correctly, the logic requires that these pointers start off as NULL.  Initializing them to NULL as this answer states is a safe (and highly recommended!) way to make sure that your variables always have the values that you expect (and require!).

Answer (score 0):

According to your code logic, you want addNode() to modify pPre. So you need to define pPre as  pointer of Node *.

```
Node * addNode(Node *pList, Node **pPre, int data)
```

And addNode() should return pList, you might miss it.

Comment: I only see it changing values inside *pPre (as pPre->...), not pPre itself, so it should work as originally declared.  They could declare it with Node **ppList (and other changes as appropriate) and be able to directly modify the list head pointer instead of returning the new value and relying on the caller to update it....  But that's just an alternate approach; the return pList approach works--with the correction as you pointed out at the end.